# Typo3 list children of a specific system category (news extension)

Tags: typo3

I have a system category tree in Typo3:

```
─┬─A─┬─A1
 │   └─A2
 │
 └─B─┬─B1
     ┼─B2
     └─B3
```

I want to render the children of B tree.

On each child news item I am able to get the categories in a string on every iteration

```
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
  <!-- render partial="List/ServiceItem" -->
  <div
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.categories}">
        data-groups="[<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" s="category" iteration="iteratorCategories">'{category.title}'<f:if condition="{iteratorCategories.isLast}"><f:then></f:then><f:else>,</f:else></f:if></f:for>]"
    </f:if>
  >{newsItem.title} & other stuff</div>
</f:for>
```

I am using Shuffle.js to filter the list and I need all the B - tree children to create the group control
I tried this:

```
<div class="news-list-category"> categories:
  <f:for each="{categories}" as="category" iteration="iteratorCategories">
    <f:if condition="{category.title} == 'B'">
      {category.title}
       <f:debug>{category.children}</f:debug>
       <f:if condition="{category.children}">
            children:
            <f:for each="{category.children}"
                      as="subCategory"
                       iteration="iteratorSubCategories">
                 <span>{subCategory.title}</span>
             </f:for>
          </f:if>
     </f:if>
  </f:for>
</div>
```

`category.children` and `category.item.children`
returns null

`<f:if condition="{category.title} == 'B'">`
gets to the correct first level item

I used
`typo3conf/ext/news/Resources/Private/Templates/Styles/Twb/Templates/Category/List.html`

as a reference as well

Should I rather do this in typoscript and pass to fluid

```
 <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.myTyposSubCategoryList" />
```

I'll go and see if I can get Typoscript to render this but would like a fluid solution

Thanks

Comment: Hi Jaco, can't you use the provided Category menu in the News extension, and simply select the categories you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

So I propose you do this:

Create a new news module in the T3 backend. And select categories as display module. You can customize the module in the `Templates/Category/List.html` file in your theme folder to change the structure and make it work with `shuffle.js`. The module needs to be included on the same page as your list module, make sure you select the site ID where the list module is to be found, and disable the `Disable overwriting of plugin settings` checkbox in the Settings tab.

In the module you simply select the categories you want to show. I think that might be the easiest way to go about this.

I used the same method to transform my categories menu into a dropdown menu:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:layout name="General" />
<!--
    =====================
        Templates/Category/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
    <f:if condition="{categories}">
        <f:then>
            <div class="news-cat-view side-news">
                <h3><f:translate key="categories" /></h3>
                <f:render section="categoryTree" arguments="{categories:categories,overwriteDemand:overwriteDemand}" />
            </div>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:translate key="list_nocategoriesfound" />
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:section>

<f:section name="categoryTree">
    <ul>
        <f:for each="{categories}" as="category">
            <li>
                <f:if condition="{category.item.uid} == {overwriteDemand.categories}">
                    <f:then>
                        <a href="javascript:;">{category.item.title}</a>
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>
                        <a href="javascript:;">{category.item.title}</a>
                    </f:else>
                </f:if>

                <f:if condition="{category.children}">
                    <f:render section="categoryTreeSub" arguments="{categories: category.children,overwriteDemand:overwriteDemand}" />
                </f:if>
            </li>
        </f:for>
        <li class="parent reset" style="display: none;"><f:link.page pageUid="22"><f:translate key="back-link" /></f:link.page></li>
    </ul>
</f:section>

<f:section name="categoryTreeSub">
    <ul>
        <f:for each="{categories}" as="category">
            <li>
                <f:if condition="{category.item.uid} == {overwriteDemand.categories}">
                    <f:then>
                        <f:link.page title="{category.item.title}" class="active" pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
                            additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: category.item.uid}}}">{category.item.title}
                        </f:link.page>
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>
                        <f:link.page title="{category.item.title}" pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
                            additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: category.item.uid}}}">{category.item.title}
                        </f:link.page>
                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
            </li>
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:section>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Scopestyle - that will work - IF: I select all the subcategories - that works with my example as well. I wanted to only select the paretn "B" and then sow all the subcatehories B1, B2..

But it seems I either have to:

Comment: But I wanted to only select the parent "B" and then show all the sub-categories B1, B2.. (Because a user can add a new sub and then will have to go to every instance of the news control and select the subs instead of just leaving the parent with "recursive" on the LIST view)

But it seems I either have to:

1. Select all the subcategories

2. Use the category list component independantly on the same page to drive the group control - it allows me to only have to select the parent and keep it simple for the editor - since the same behaviour will be on 4 diff. pages

Comment: because when I only select the parent and use the category menu list template in:
\typo3conf\ext\sx_news_extend\Resources\Private\Templates\Category\List.html
it works - but not if I use the same code as part of the News List Template - It only shows the selected cat and not subs - I still have to try Typoscript though

Comment: So what if you look for categories by ID, does that make a difference in your code? - <f:if condition="{category.uid} == 1">

Comment: I can show all the subcategories of a parent in the category list view and I went that route (Categroy\List.html) Modified a new template based on the category/list view to drive the category menu/filter control. The only issue is it shows categories that have no articles linked to it. If I use the detail view then only categories specifically selected in the back-end shows - Selecting the parent only shows the parent in the same code for the category list. Back-end admins will have to remember to go and specifically select a sub-category to make the control work. So both is not perfect.

Comment: A 3rd option is to create the html dynamically for the control through JavaScript since I do not worry about SEO for the control. As each individual list item gets rendered it adds it's category to a list sorting unique entries... I might just stay with the solution of using the Category/List rendered control since it works.